# Why am I getting a file not found error in java using OSX, but not Windows?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm a java n00b, so please excuse any ignorance.

I'm trying to run a TestNG test in IntelliJ on OSX, but when I do, I get the following file not found error:

```
File: src/test/resources/manager/MemberTest/testCreating.csv not found.
```

However, when my colleagues run this on their Windows machines, the test completes and they do not get the same error. One such colleague's file was located at

```
D:\trunk_QA\src\test\resources\manager\MemberTest\testCreating.csv
```

Mine is located at

```
/Users/username/QA Materials/Automation/Framework/trunk_QA/src/test/resources/manager/MemberTest/testCreating.csv
```

The dataSourcePath seems to be correctly laid out as a relative path:

```
private static String dataSourcePath = "src/test/resources/";
```

And when run with that dataSourcePath, I get the error.

If I update it to use my local absolute path:

```
private static String dataSourcePath = "/Users/username/QA Materials/Automation/Framework/trunk_QA/src/test/resources/";
```

The test then passes. However, I can't check this in because outside of being a poor practice to use absolute links, it will break the test on my coworkers' machines.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to define a system variable such as CLASSPATH?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with backslash being used in windows in opposite to the regular slash in OSX and Linux?

Comment: Those relative paths are going to be relative from the .class files(or rather from where the app was actually initialized). Not from the .java files. Which could be relevant depending on the IDE that they are using, or even the configuration of each IDE (where to store resources, etc.)

Comment: try adding this right before to see if your files are in the right place: `System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: See my comment below in the answer... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with I would suggest using `File.separator` instead of slashes as they will be guaranteed to be cross-platform.

If that doesn't make it work you could try this:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
```

That will print the actual directory you are in. Perhaps you are not where you think you are?

Comment: OK, I updated 
'private static String dataSourcePath = "src/test/resources/"' to
'private static String dataSourcePath = ("src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "resources")'
No joy. I get a new error: 'cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable File'

Using @Cruncher's code to get the current path, I find that when dataSourcePath is set to src/test/resources/, I get a blank here:
'System.getProperty("user.dir") = '
When dataSourcePath is set to /Users/username/QA Materials/Automation/Framework/trunk_QA/src/test/resources/, I get the path that I'd expect:
'/Users/elock/QA Materials'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to edit the working directory under Run>Edit Configurations>TestNG. When I imported the project, it set that working directory all on its own, and to the wrong thing!

The reason it wasn't printing the user.dir when the dataSourcePath was set to src/test/resources/ is that it was erroring out before it hit that chunk of code.

Overall, a pretty simple solution if you know what you're doing with setting up IntelliJ.

Thank you to everyone for your help! I learned all sorts of new stuff.